Qt qmlformat unwanted behaviour
I use qmlformat in Qt Creator to format my QML files, using these options, but sometime later it started to add new option --inplace and program stopped working with this error: Error in text formatting: Failed to format: The command "/home/user/Qt/6.7.0/gcc_64/bin/qmlformat --normalize --indent-width 2 --objects-spacing --functions-spacing --force --inplace /tmp/QtCreator-iZOaRU/qtc_beautifier_kCRiQkSB.qml" terminated with exit code 1...
I haven't found where this new option might be inserted in Qt Creator settings, Google also didn't help much. Did somebody encounter this thing in Qt Creator?

Yes, Qt Creator adds --inplace no matter what. You can workaround it and run qmlformat with your own arguments.
Create ~/format.sh:
#!/bin/bash -e
tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
~/Qt/6.7.0/gcc_64/bin/qmlformat --normalize --indent-width 2 --objects-spacing --functions-spacing "$1" > "$tmpfile"
mv "$tmpfile" "$1"

Make it executable: chmod +x ~/format.sh
Use this settings in Qt Creator:

Command: ~/format.sh
Arguments: "%{CurrentDocument:FilePath}"



Not exactly what I'm talking about, somehow Qt Creator adds new option --inplace, which breaks formatting and I don't know where it comes from. I also corrected my question and added screenshot of my settings window.

I updated the answer. But I also recommend filing a bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-126576?jql=project%20%3D%20QTBUG%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22QML%3A%20Tooling%22
